MariaDB Query takes longer than same DB in Mysql
I am migrating a Db from Mysql  8.0.23 to MariaDB 11.3.2 and I realize that some queries needs longer in MariaDB than in Mysql. It is the same query and same DB structure. In MariaDB I need to get a response o this quera 3.5 seconds and in the mysql server only 0.8 seconds. I perform a Explain and Analyze command and I saw that the run procedure are different. Because I would proceed to see how many rows are evaluated, and create some indexes but I dont the rows evaluated are similar. How can I optimize the mariaDB db? Have you any hints how to proceed to optimize the db? Thank you in advance!
Best Regards,
Paul
There is the query:
 select  `q`.*, EXISTS (
    SELECT `qe`.* FROM `questions` `qe`     
    CROSS JOIN `companies_has_users` `cu` ON cu.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_groups` `ag` ON ag.question_id = qe.id AND ag.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af` ON af.answer_group_id = ag.id AND af.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a` ON a.answer_field_id = af.id AND a.is_answered = 1 AND a.user_id = cu.user_id AND a.questionnaire_id = 228 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a_2` ON a_2.answer_field_id = af.id AND a_2.is_default = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_2` ON af_2.id = a.answer_field_id AND af_2.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_3` ON af_3.id = a_2.answer_field_id AND af_3.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `questions_has_user_files` `quf` ON quf.question_id = qe.id AND quf.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `questionnaires_has_questions` `qhq` ON qhq.question_id = qe.id
    WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`qe`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (qe.id = q.id) AND (`a`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) AS `count_answers`, 
    EXISTS (SELECT `qe`.* FROM `questions` `qe` 
    CROSS JOIN `companies_has_users` `cu` ON cu.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_groups` `ag` ON ag.question_id = qe.id AND ag.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af` ON af.answer_group_id = ag.id AND af.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a` ON a.answer_field_id = af.id AND a.is_answered = 1 AND a.user_id = cu.user_id AND a.questionnaire_id = 228 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a_2` ON a_2.answer_field_id = af.id AND a_2.is_default = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_2` ON af_2.id = a.answer_field_id AND af_2.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_3` ON af_3.id = a_2.answer_field_id AND af_3.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `questions_has_user_files` `quf` ON quf.question_id = qe.id AND quf.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `questionnaires_has_questions` `qhq` ON qhq.question_id = qe.id 
    WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`qe`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (qe.id = q.id) AND (`a_2`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) AS `count_default_answers`, 
    EXISTS (SELECT `qe`.* FROM `questions` `qe` 
    CROSS JOIN `companies_has_users` `cu` ON cu.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_groups` `ag` ON ag.question_id = qe.id AND ag.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af` ON af.answer_group_id = ag.id AND af.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a` ON a.answer_field_id = af.id AND a.is_answered = 1 AND a.user_id = cu.user_id AND a.questionnaire_id = 228 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a_2` ON a_2.answer_field_id = af.id AND a_2.is_default = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_2` ON af_2.id = a.answer_field_id AND af_2.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_3` ON af_3.id = a_2.answer_field_id AND af_3.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `questions_has_user_files` `quf` ON quf.question_id = qe.id AND quf.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `questionnaires_has_questions` `qhq` ON qhq.question_id = qe.id 
    WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`qe`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (qe.id = q.id) AND ((`af_2`.`user_upload_enabled`=2) OR (`af_3`.`user_upload_enabled`=2))) AS `user_upload_enabled`, 
    EXISTS (SELECT `qe`.* FROM `questions` `qe` 
    CROSS JOIN `companies_has_users` `cu` ON cu.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_groups` `ag` ON ag.question_id = qe.id AND ag.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af` ON af.answer_group_id = ag.id AND af.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a` ON a.answer_field_id = af.id AND a.is_answered = 1 AND a.user_id = cu.user_id AND a.questionnaire_id = 228 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` `a_2` ON a_2.answer_field_id = af.id AND a_2.is_default = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_2` ON af_2.id = a.answer_field_id AND af_2.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `answer_fields` `af_3` ON af_3.id = a_2.answer_field_id AND af_3.archived = 0 
    LEFT JOIN `questions_has_user_files` `quf` ON quf.question_id = qe.id AND quf.company_id = 160 
    LEFT JOIN `questionnaires_has_questions` `qhq` ON qhq.question_id = qe.id 
    WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`qe`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (qe.id = q.id) AND ((`quf`.`file_id` IS NOT NULL) AND (`quf`.`questionnaire_id`=228))) AS `has_user_file_id` FROM `questions` `q` 
    LEFT JOIN `questionnaires_has_questions` `qhq` ON qhq.question_id = q.id 
    WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`q`.`archived`=FALSE) 
    GROUP BY `q`.`id` ORDER BY `count_answers` DESC, `count_default_answers` DESC

And I perform a Explain in both servers to know how if I found something to optimzie and I get:
bot explain tables (converted in images) :
explain of mariaDB: 
explain of mysql: 
UPDATE 23.06.2024: I added the images of both explains. And deleted the table in Markdown.

SQL Server appears to be irrelevant here, so I have removed the tag. Please don't tag unrelated technologies.

Honestly, I'm impressed that MariaDB was able to run in just 3.5 seconds.  There are lots of reasons why the query might seem to take longer on your new MariaDB instance, such as the new DB is not in heavy use while the legacy MySQL system has a production load on it.

All those LEFT JOINs have a smell, they're in an EXISTS, so the LEFT JOINs are pointless.

Do you have some test data, as well as the creates and the expected result. It's not just the query that can be optimized. It may also be that the configuration is incorrect and the optimizer chooses other ways to execute the query

how can I get the test data and the configuration? is something wrong in the configuration of the server? how can I know that?

Can you show at least part of the MySQL explain?

Remove LEFT JOINS where there are no other JOINs or WHERE criteria that depend on them. WHERE xxx.id IS NOT NULL is an indiction that its an INNER JOIN and the IS NOT NULL can be removed. There should be no remaining LEFT JOINs, EXIST (SELECT qe.* can be simplified to EXISTS (SELECT 1 ..... Factor the common aspects of what is left into a CTE.

I updated the questions for include both explains. Someone could tell me why both explains are different? What is doing mariaDB different?

An optimizer trace would show how it made the decision. Comparing it to how MySQL made its decision is more guess work. A reduced test case might be worthy of a bug report.

Is there WHERE clause the only thing that is different in the 4 subqueries?

Can you highlight the differences in the Explains?


I have concluded that the subqueries are all the same except for there WHERE clauses.

The usual phrasing is simply EXPLAIN SELECT 1 ... (instead of *).  (This does not impact performance.)

The 4 subqueries seem to be doing mostly the same thing; can you somehow JOIN to a single copy of the common stuff in them?

The WHEREs seem to have this in common:
WHERE ((`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 228) OR (`qhq`.`questionnaire_id` = 149)) AND (`qe`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (qe.id = q.id)


The OR is costly.  Doing 1 copy instead of 4 could be a speedup.

And vary in
AND (`a`.`id` IS NOT NULL)  -- `count_answers`, 
AND(`a_2`.`id` IS NOT NULL)  ) --`count_default_answers`, 
AND ((`af_2`.`user_upload_enabled`=2) OR (`af_3`.`user_upload_enabled`=2)) --`user_upload_enabled`, 
AND ((`quf`.`file_id` IS NOT NULL) AND (`quf`.`questionnaire_id`=228))  -- `has_user_file_id` 



